# Designing a proof mechanism

Tags: design, interfaces, circular-dependency, abstract-factory, command-pattern

`DataModel` contains a `Proof` that contains all the information of its integrity along with the method with which the `Proof` should be verified.

In this case I designed a `JWS` type of proof that can be generated by using a `ProofGenerator` object that contains the private key to calculate the `Proof`. However each time a `DataModel` must be verified a public key must be provided by the verifier, which means that the public key (that is the information needed for the verification) is not included into the `Proof`.

A possible solution would be to define a new `ProofMethod` class that contains all the information to perform the verification and pass it to the `verify` method of the `Proof` that contains the logic to do that.

Is there a better way to design this mechanism by including all the necessary information in the `Proof` class to do the verification knowing that the information needed for that must be provided and not included (in this case the public key) when the `Proof` is created?

Another problem is that who receive the `DataModel` must recognize the `Proof` type otherwise it is not able to provide the `ProofMethod` necessary to do the verification.

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit this to include an actual question? At the moment, it's just a statement of what you've done - thanks!

Comment: @PhilipKendall is it clear now?